# How did Ben use Feedback in Store 23?

Tags: ben-10, ben-10-omniverse

I've just finished watching [*Showdown: Part 1*](https://ben10.fandom.com/wiki/Showdown:_Part_1) and it was revealed in that episode that [Feedback](https://ben10.fandom.com/wiki/Feedback) was destroyed by [Malware](https://ben10.fandom.com/wiki/Malware) and Ben can no longer turn into Feedback, but I've seen 16-year-old Ben turn into Feedback in [*Store 23*](https://ben10.fandom.com/wiki/Store_23).

Did the events of *Store 23* take place after *Showdown: Part 1*?

Could anyone explain to me what's going on? (Note: I haven't watched *Showdown: Part 2* yet.)

[image: Ben as 16-year-old Feedback in Store 23.]
***Ben as 16-year-old Feedback in Store 23.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Ben 10 Wiki, 16-year-old Ben regains access to Feedback during the events of [Showdown: Part 2](https://ben10.fandom.com/wiki/Showdown:_Part_2):

> Suddenly, Ben, in the form of Feedback, emerges from Malware's head. Malware is shocked, but says that he will destroy Feedback again.

It's unclear to both me and the Wiki how 16-year-old Ben was able to do this:

> [Feedback] is one of the four regular aliens to be temporarily destroyed and removed from the original Omnitrix/Ultimatrix [...] While Ben has been able to regain the other aliens, **it remains unclear as to how he was able to regain Feedback**.
>
> ~[Ben 10 Wiki's page on Feedback](https://ben10.fandom.com/wiki/Feedback#Trivia) (emphasis mine)

What *is* clear is that, following the events of the Showdown two-parter, 11-year-old Ben can no longer use Feedback, but 16-year-old Ben can. While Store 23 aired before the Showdown two-parter in the US, its events actually takes place afterwards, explaining how 16-year-old Ben is about to use Feedback.

I realise this may not be the most satisfying answer, but it honestly appears that there is no canon explanation for how Ben was able to regain use of Feedback.

Comment: Did the events of Store 23 take place after Showdown: Part 1?


Note: I haven't watched Showdown: Part 2 yet.

Comment: You spoiled Showdown: Part 2 for me, by the way.

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have asked if you'd watched Showdown: Part 2 first, before posting this. But yes, Store 23 chronologically takes place after the Showdown two-parter, though for some reason it was aired in the US first.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I get it now.

Comment: "Yes, Store 23 chronologically takes place after the Showdown two-parter" --- I needed to hear this.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I think Store 23 is after this event; one instance is Ben's motorcycle, which isn't even made until later in season 3